# MS SQL SERVER connection timout on different schema on same server

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

'''

```
    Try
        Dim connectionString As String = "Server=" & SERVER_NAME & ";Database=" & DB_NAME & ";User Id=" & USER_ID & ";Password=" & PASSWORD_STRING
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            conn.Open()
            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CUSTOM_VIEW", conn)

                adapter.Fill(dtCustom_view)

            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...")
        Console.ReadKey()
        Environment.Exit(0)

    End Try
```

'''

Problem is when connection is made to DB_NAME="One" works fine, when DB_NAME="Two" exeption is rised

Both schemas are on the same server. I can connect to both schemas using ODBC with same username and password. Problem rised after user have upgraded SQL server to compatibility level 2019. Prior it was 2008 and there were no problem to connect to both schemas.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
at iSAF.Module1.Main(String[] args)
ClientConnectionId:ba3bf0f6-683d-4394-9d4d-43948269e5da
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11

Comment: FYI, those are databases, not schemas. Also, it looks like it's a command timeout rather than a connection timeout.

Comment: Is the timeout on `.open` or `.fill` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like you have a performance issue on that view. Please share both execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also show us the tables and *index definitions*

Comment: Full exeption text added.  I'm able to connect using Excel to both databases and get data from same view using same credentials.

Comment: Data fills corectly after SQL Server compatibility downgrade to 2008.

Comment: As I said, we need to see table indexes and execution plans. The whole stack trace is not necessary. The timeout is almost certainly a performance issue from SQL Server, and nothing to do with ADO.Net

Comment: _Problem rised after user have upgraded SQL server_ Suggest you and "user" have a discussion about upgrading and debugging problems that result from the upgrade. More than likely your view needs to be tuned. You can't stay in 2008 compatibility forever.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem rised after user have upgraded SQL server to compatibility level 2019. Prior it was 2008 and there were no problem to connect to both schemas.

You should turn on [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) to gather query performance baselines before increasing the compatibility level.